# Overwrite Wordpress's URL rewrite not working

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

What I'm trying to do it's pretty much simple, but it's not working and I don't know if it's a Wordpress rewrite or I'm just doing it wrong.

What I have is this url:

```
http://www.example.com/newsletter/?ut=token
```

And I want `.htaccess` to write it as following:

```
http://www.example.com/newsletter/confirm/token
```

Same thing for this:

```
http://www.example.com/newsletter/?uc=token
```

Which should be rewritten as:

```
http://www.example.com/newsletter/delete/token
```

This is my actual `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^newsletter/confirm/(.+)/?$ index.php?page_id=4058&ut=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^newsletter/delete/(.+)/?$ index.php?page_id=4058&del=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

4058 is the id of newsletter page. I've also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^newsletter/confirm/(.+)/?$ newsletter/?ut=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^newsletter/delete/(.+)/?$ newsletter/?del=$1 [L,NC]
```

But it still not working at all. With the first method it goes to newsletter page without query string ( so it gives an empty page ); with the second one it gives 404 Not found.

I've also tried using Wordpress's built-in function `add_rewrite_rule` without success, this is what I've tried:

```
function customRewriteRules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^newsletter/confirm/(.+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=4058&ut=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^newsletter/delete/(.+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=4058&del=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'customRewriteRules');
```

Could it be something related to a kind of rewrite priority for Wordpress's base rewrite conditions? Or am I just doing it bad?

Comment: `add_rewrite_url()` should work but `add_rewrite_endpoint()` seems more appropiated for your case. Can you show to us the code you have tried?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote `add_rewrite_url()` instead of `add_rewrite_rule()`

Comment: Please check the update question

Comment: Your code seems fine. Have you flushed the rewrite rules after adding the snippet? You can flush rewrite rules by vivisting to the admin area Settings->Permalinks and clicking the save buttong or by using [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) (**do it only on plugin activation/deactivation hook**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has its own rewriting system in PHP so you can do it both ways

If you want to rewrite these url from htaccess, i would only make it rewrite

`http://www.example.com/newsletter/confirm/token` to `http://www.example.com/newsletter/?ut=token`

instead of trying to rewrite `http://www.example.com/newsletter/confirm/token` to `http://www.example.com/index.php?page_id=4058&ut=token`

And let WordPress handle the page id rewrite.

So the htaccess rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^newsletter/confirm/(.+)/?$ /newsletter/?ut=$1 [L,NC]
```

Alternatively you can define your rewrite rule in the WordPress rewrite system:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^newsletter/confirm/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=4058&ut=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Anyway, to access this new query variable you have to declare it in WordPress aswell:

```
add_filter('query_vars','my_add_ut_query_var');

function my_add_ut_query_var($vars) {
    array_push($vars, 'designer');
    return $vars;
}
```

Now you can access it from your page template:

```
$token = get_query_var('ut')
```

And don"t forget to flush your rules when you add a new one of course :)

(Also be careful you have a typo with your `uc` or `ut` parameter)

Comment: Are you saying that my second `RewriteRule` was ok? Anyway, `newsletter/confirm` doesn't exist, why did you put in in yours `RewriteRule`? P.S. I've tried your rewrite rule but it's not working :(

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer, my RewriteRule was false. The important point for you i think is to add the query_vars filter.

Comment: Ok, something has started working. Now I need to check if there are those query_vars. I'll accept your answer as soon as I go back to the office. Thank you :)